# How do I increase the interval of a plot in julia

Tags: plot, julia

I would like to have my coordinate system to increase in size. In other words I want that my x- and y-axis goes from -10 to 10. I tried using `size=()` but it ended up just squaring the plot. Down below is my code, any help is appreciated.

```
using Plots

x = [-10]
y = [-2]

scatter(x, y,   label=false, size=(400,400))
scatter!([0], [0], label=false)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`xlims!`](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/api/#Plots.xlims!-Tuple%7BTuple%7D) function to update the x-cooridnation limits:

```
julia> xlims!(-10, 10)
```

And on your example:

```
using Plots

x = [-10]
y = [-2]

scatter(x, y,   label=false, size=(400,400))
scatter!([0], [0], label=false)
# set xlim from -11 to 10
xlims!(-11, 10)
```

[image]

Lastly, as HenrikWolf mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74544001/how-do-i-increase-the-interval-of-a-plot-in-julia/74544402?noredirect=1#comment131588252_74544402), for similar questions If someone wants to set the limits early on, they can set the `xlims` keyword argument in the `scatter` function:

```
scatter(x, y, label=false, size=(400,400), xlims=(-11, 10))
```

Comment: You also can almost always plug stuff like that directly into your plot command. For your example, you could just do: `scatter(x, y,   label=false, size=(400,400), xlims=(-10,10))`.